# AlertDialog buttons positioning

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a simple dialog in Kotlin:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok"){dialog, _ ->
                }
                .setNeutralButton("Wait") {dialog, _ ->
                }
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->                   
                }
                .show()
```

However, the orders that buttons showing as :

---

> Wait  Cancel  Ok

---

What I expected is :

---

> Cancel  Wait Ok

---

Is this possible without creating custom layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your question. I've had a go at this and I switched the buttons around and finally got to this:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMessage("Message")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok"){dialog, _ ->
        }
        .setNeutralButton("Cancel") {dialog, _ ->
        }
        .setNegativeButton("Wait") { dialog, _ ->
        }
        .show()
```

Outputs this `AlertDialog`:

[image]

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah this is a simple fix but the `positive` and `negative` has no diff other than its name? I was trying to avoid this coz it makes my code looks bad when I implement event listeners for each button afterwards